# int() vs .astype('int') Python

Tags: python

I'm not sure when to use `int()` and when to use `.astype('int')`. Can anyone explain?

Is it just `int()` is used for single values and `.astype('int')` is used for vectors? I'm coming from an R background so I'm used to using `as.integer`

Comment: `numpy` and `pandas` are two specialized libraries in the Python ecosystem. R as a language specialized for statistical/scientific computing to begin with, Python has a much more generalist ecosystem. `int` plays a pretty central role in the Python data model. `int` is meant as a hook for allowing user-defined types to be converted to the standard built-in `int` type, which is non-fixed width. It just happens that `numpy`/`pandas` ecosystem is very concerned with various fix-sized integer types, because the core data-structure are multidimensional, homogeneously, fixed-size arrays.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`.astype()` is a method within [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), as well as the Pandas [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype) class, so can be used to convert vectors, matrices and columns within a `DataFrame`. However, `int()` is a pure-Python function that can only be applied to scalar values.

For example, you can do `int(3.14)`, but can't do `(2.7).astype('int')`, because Python native types don't have any such method. However, `numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3]).astype('int')` is valid.

(Strictly, it is also possible to define an `__int__()` method within one's own classes, which would allow `int()` to be applied to non-native types. Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga for pointing this out.)

Comment: To be fair, and I forgot this, but `__int__` enforces returning an `int`. But, the point still stands, some user-defined `array` could easily be *consumed* by the `int` function.

Answer (score 1):

astype is a numpy function, as @rwp points out. It is defined as:

```
def astype(self, typecode):
        ""
        return self._rc(self.array.astype(typecode))
```

._rc is defined as:

```
def _rc(self, a):
    if len(shape(a)) == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return self.__class__(a)
```

In English, this means that if your array has no shape -- i.e. it's a list -- it returns the array, else it returns the array itself cast to the indicated type.

int is a python builtin. It only deals with scalars.